# Maximum normalization

Tags: mysql, php, normalization

I have been studying the normal forms rules to guide me with database design and data storage, the problem I am having is that once I optimize for the first normal form (**1NF**), I figured I may well just go the whole way(even though not mandatory).

However a occurrence showed in my design that I haven't came across in examples online or books.

A example concept.

We want to store all data about the some car variations.

We must store values make, series, model, start year, end year.

**Unormalized**

```
+------+--------+-------+------------+----------+
| make | series | model | start year | end year |
+------+--------+-------+------------+----------+
| BMW  |   5    |  E12  |    1972    |   1981   |
| BMW  |   5    |  E28  |    1981    |   1988   |
| BMW  |   5    |  E34  |    1988    |   1996   |
| BMW  |   5    |  E39  |    1995    |   2004   |
+------+--------+-------+------------+----------+
```

**Normalized**

```
car_make

+----+------+
| id | make | 
+----+------+
| 1  | BMW  | 
+----+------+

car_series

+----+--------+---------+
| id | series | make_id |
+----+--------+---------+
| 1  |   1    |    1    |
| 2  |   3    |    1    |
| 3  |   5    |    1    |
| 4  |   7    |    1    |
+----+--------+---------+

car_model

+----+-------+------------+----------+-------- --+
| id | model | start year | end year | series_id |
+----+-------+------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  |  E12  |    1972    |   1981   |     3     |
| 2  |  E28  |    1981    |   1988   |     3     | 
| 3  |  E34  |    1988    |   1996   |     3     | 
| 4  |  E39  |    1995    |   2004   |     3     |  
+----+-------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

One problem arises here in the last table, should I also include a column make_id in the car_model table?

It is beneficial as I would not have to join car_series, then select make_id, to select make by id, however I believe this may not be sticking to normalization, because I would be repeating data(even though it is a id its still repeat).

Can this design be normalized further?

On another note with regards to the start year, end year handling, How would you professionals do this? I am curios if there is any range tricks to enforce integrity(although the E39 overlaps, lets speak as though no dates overlap).

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should not include a column make_id in the car_model table, it is implicitly defined by the series_id.  If you need to see the make details you could make a view that looks like your un-normalized table.

No this design cannot be normalised further.

To force the year ranges to be non-overlapping you could add a trigger (as MySql does not support check constraints) to ensure that `start_year >= max(end_year)` and `end_year >= start_year`.

The trigger would look something like this:

```
create trigger trg_car_model_date_range_unique before insert on car_model
for each row
begin
    if new.start_year < (select max(end_year) from car_model) then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Date range is not unique';
    end if;
    if new.end_year < new.start_year then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Date range is invalid';
    end if;
end
```

Comment: How would you code the `start_year >= max(end_year)` constraint and what exactly would it solve?

Comment: ... Don't know why MySQL does not have check constraints... Anyway, answer updated with solution and clarification.